# 'take the address with &' what's that meaning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

a function named getTimerInterval returned a NSTimerInterval value

```
-(NSTimeInterval *)getInterval {
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
    return interval;
}
```

Xcode warn me

> Returning 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') from a function with
>   incompatible result type 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *'); take the
>   address with &" on the line "return interval"

well, NSInteger type is fine:

```
-(NSIntefer)getInteger {
    NSIntefer result = 1;
    return result;
}
```

as well as return number directly:

```
 -(NSTimeInterval *)getInterval {
     return 1;
 }
```

OK, after that calling getInterval function got a warning:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[self getInterval] target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

> Sending 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') to parameter of
>   incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double'); dereference with *

I am confused with & and *, where should I have to use & or *?
what's that meaning actually?
I just know it's c++ syntax about pointer or something, thank in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix the compiler warning, you'd need to return the address of it, like this:

```
-(NSTimeInterval *)getInterval {
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
    return &interval;
}
```

**However that is bad** as you will return the address on the method's stack frame which disappears after return.  Why not just return it like this:

```
-(NSTimeInterval)getInterval {
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
    return interval;
}
```

Which I believe will also fix your other compiler error.

Comment: your second code sample seems same with my first code sample and Xcode give me a warning. It's unuseful if return the address of var(&interval) caused of it will be collected while function is completed, am I not reading into this right?

Comment: @rock Your first code sample returned `NSTimeInterval *` not `NSTimeInterval`.

Comment: ho~finally got the root cause, I really shouldn't return var pointer in a function, you help me a lot, thanks @trojanfoe :)

Answer (score 0):

It's basic C (and therefore objective-c) syntax, meaning "address of variable" (`&`), and the reverse "value at address" (`*`). The address is called a *pointer*. There are hundreds of sites out there explaining this in great detail.

A simple example:

```
NSInteger i=1;
NSInteger *ptr;

ptr = &i;

NSLog(@"The pointer %p points to value %d (which is equal to %d)",ptr,*ptr,i);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but may confuse the OP.  If he just adds a & to his first code example, he'll be returning the address of a local variable.

Comment: @CarlNorum I agree, but whatever the OP does, the first thing should be to have a good read about pointers.

Comment: I agree with @CarlNorum -- I think the OP is confused about using pointers to classes vs. typedef primitive types like NSInteger or NSTimeInterval. It's a very common issue for people new to Objective-C and C

Comment: @JasonCoco so what better than to start reading about pointers in general? The actual question seems to be "where should I have to use & or \*? what's that meaning actually?"

Comment: thanks guys, actually when asking this question I just want to know principles of & and * just like memory management is iOS, and why NSIngeter could run well but NSTimeInterval not? now I realize maybe it's necessary to learn what is and how to use pointer,it will help me make great progress.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers in objective-C are literal bits of memory, so when you pass around a value with a pointer (*), it's memory address comes along for the ride.  The ampersand on the other hand, literally means "the address of", and is usually used for primitive data type variables such as int, BOOL, double, etc in cases where we want the method to modify the variable itself (often what it points to as well) and return a useable value.  NSError follows this logic fairly consistently.